# Moderator declines to restore deleted useful comments that an answer referred to, so I *can't* now add them to my answer

Tags: discussion, flags, comments, moderation, deleted-comments

(Update: apparently the decline message was a canned response, thanks @Cerbrus for helping me see this from the moderator perspective.  Apparently people waste moderator time asking for non-useful comments to be restored; I hadn't considered the possibility that my flag could look like such a request to a moderator.  I assumed it was obvious that deleted comments should get undeleted if someone asked, because comments get over-zealously deleted all the time.  In hindsight my flag could have made a clearer argument for undeletion.
But I still stand by the position that comments can be useful, and are better than nothing for info that people haven't found the time or energy to fit into the answer proper.)

(I also didn't realize that the deleted comments *had* been moved to chat, just a glitch in the script also deleted the moved-to-chat comment. So there was never a moderator intent to fully delete them.
Thanks to Martijn restoring that comment; I've updated my answer to link the chat transcript.  If I have time at some point, I might add a section to the answer summarizing the discussion.)

---

My answer on [Is there a way to "unfetch" a cache line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51343231/is-there-a-way-to-unfetch-a-cache-line/51344347#51344347) says "See discussion in comments: this might perform significantly worse. ..." in bold.  I wrote it in 2018, and don't still remember what the comments said exactly, but I assume the comments under the answer were interesting enough for me to write in bold that readers should have a look at them.  And I assume they're *still* relevant now.

I happened to look at that answer again while searching for something else the other day, and noticed that there are no comments under it now.  Obviously that's not good, there was useful info there for future readers. So I flagged for a moderator to restore them:

> Please restore comments under this answer that says "see discussion in comments" in **bold**. I don't recall what that comments were, but I assume when I wrote it that I thought they were valuable

**The flag was declined with an utterly unhelpful message, in terms of doing something about the situation now with the comments already gone.**  I said in the flag I don't remember what was in them, so I can't now add them to my answer.

> declined - Comments aren't for extended discussions. If it's important, extend your answer.

Which is true, but it didn't happen at the time, due to limits on the amount of time & effort I was willing to put into that answer then.  I know comments are nominally ephemeral, but usually useful comments don't get nuked, especially on obscure answers.  (They do on popular canonical answers where new comments tend to accumulate over time).

Am I supposed to go digging on archive.org to see if I can find a copy of the page from before the deletion?

---

**This "your ball is in my yard now and you can't have it back" attitude is not something I'm ok with.**  I *hope* that wasn't the intent behind the phrasing of the decline, but that's how it comes across to me.  That's part of why I'm bringing this to meta.

But also because **the comments shouldn't have been deleted in the first place**.  There's just no need for it.  Whoever flagged them "no longer needed" was wrong, because the answer hadn't yet been updated to contain that info, and it was highly relevant (IIRC) to the question, and to most future readers who found the answer useful.

If they'd submitted an edit to add a new section that covers whatever had been discussed in comments, that would have been good.  (As long as it wasn't just a blockquote of all the comments; at that point it would be better to leave them as comments).  Then, once the edit had been accepted, the comments would no longer be needed.  When the answer says *in bold* to see comments, that's a textbook case of comments that are still needed.

---

I know I'm not the only person who thinks Stack Overflow's comment policy of being subject to arbitrary deletion at any time is not good, for example @zwol has expressed this multiple times on meta.  I'm ok with that being a *possibility*, as long as the judgment is made by reasonable humans who don't delete useful comments that are directly relevant to the answer, only off topic or chatty stuff like "I'll edit when I get back from my Ultimate frisbee game :)".

The comments on that one answer aren't that important in the grand scheme of things, but the general principle here is a *huge* deal to me.  Getting useful comments moved to chat is bad enough (many people will skim at least the high-voted comments to see if there's something interesting to them, but chat loses voting, and almost nobody opens it in the first place).  But deleting and refusing to restore when it's pointed out that they were useful is way way beyond that.  To me, that shows total disregard for Stack Overflow being a repository of useful information.

**There are only so many hours in a day, and we don't always have time and energy to include everything commenters have to add.  Comments make useful footnotes.**  This works great unless/until people come along and delete comments just because they can, without care for them being relevant and useful.  Everything that's directly relevant to answering the question *should* be in the answer, and usually is, but not everything is perfect.

---

If even useful comments are at real risk of deletion, I guess every time I see an old answer with anything wrong with it (especially by an inactive user), I should just edit it as well as / instead of commenting, despite "intent" of the author?  e.g. changing code or adding sections explaining why something earlier in the answer is actually not a good idea?  That seems messier and way more intrusive, but apparently if we don't want our efforts to help future readers to vanish because someone randomly pressed a button, we need to make sure everything helpful is in answers.

I often add a comment to warn future readers of a possible problem or downside with an old answer, often to explain why (part of) it is wrong if I downvoted.  Because editing "this answer is wrong" into an answer doesn't seem good, nor does deleting whole paragraphs.  (If the answer has previous upvotes, one downvote won't make its score negative, so won't signal to future readers that it's not fully correct.)

Comment: _"This "your ball is in my yard now and you can't have it back" attitude is not something I'm ok with."_ I think you're severely overestimating this "attitude", and taking this way too personally. That flag response you got was just a default message, to what on first sight looks like a dime-a-dozen _"I don't want my comments deleted"_ flag. You could've written this as a request to restore the comment, or you could've used a well worded custom flag, and that would've been problem solved. Instead, there's this (argumentative) wall of text...

Comment: @Cerbrus: I think the attitude towards deleting useful comments on Stack Overflow is bad, and worth arguing against.  This flag-decline was motivation to say something about it.  And why would I try raising another flag?  It was already declined once, for reasons that make no sense to me.  Apparently some moderator is against having useful comments.  I didn't know comments had been moved to chat and there was just one link to restore.  I don't know what different phrasing would get a different response (without the benefit of your suggestion on how it might have looked to a mod).

Comment: How can you claim the comments should not have been deleted because they were still useful, and at the same time not know what they said? If you don't remember what the comments said, you can't argue they were still useful, no matter how many reminders you left yourself. If the comments were truly that useful, you would've ostensibly added the relevant info to the question at the time instead of adding a note that said "see comments".

Comment: @Cerbrus: I *thought* it was totally obvious that useful comments should be restored, and as a high-rep user my opinion would be somewhat trusted.  So just being told I should have extended my answer seemed very rude.

Comment: Again, you're taking this waaaaaaaay too personally. Mods handle way too many flags to care about something at irrelevant as rep. Nobody is being rude, it's just a default message.

Comment: @TylerH: Like I explained in this question: In 2018, hours after the answer was posted, I edited it to say "see discussion in comments...", and put that in bold.  Obviously at the time I thought the comments were useful and relevant.  My 2022 self trusted the opinion of my 2018 self, and assumed the comments were still useful and relevant.

Comment: *"after the answer was posted, I edited it to say "see discussion in comments...""* Why would you do that when you know that comments can and do get deleted..? Why didn't you add the information from the comments to the answer?

Comment: If you disagree with how something works on SO/SE, _suggest_ a better alternative, and _convince_ readers of why it's better. Don't rant about how the status quo is so bad. Don't argue, don't fight. That'll only make your suggestion seem weaker.

Comment: @Cerbrus: I also didn't know it was a default message, that makes it significantly less bad in hindsight.  But yes, I really was upset by it.  Not so much *personally*, but in terms of how can a moderator be that unhelpful, as well as the general attitude toward deletion of useful comments. I think it's obvious what I'm suggesting: apply judgement and don't delete useful comments, especially under low-traffic posts.  Maybe sometime later when I'm not still mad, I'll post about it in general.

Comment: @Larnu: I already spend lots of time every day contributing to Stack Overflow.  I simply don't have the time or motivation to make every answer perfect.  I do the best I can and have the energy for.  Sometimes that means referring people to comments, under the assumption that highly useful ones won't be deleted for no good reason, especially if an answer points out that they're useful.  If you're unhappy with the amount of effort I put into my answers, do you want to pay me to spend even more time on them?  No, didn't think so.

Comment: _"Useful"_ is subjective. Looking at that chat, there's a ___lot___ of discussion, and it probably takes a SME to distill useful information out of it... Which should've been distilled into the answer. You don't _have_ to make the answer perfect, but you not having the time to edit useful information into your answer isn't a reason not to move those comments.

Comment: And the moderators have *a lot* of flags to work through, @PeterCordes . You can't expect them to check the answer(s) on a question to see if they are referencing a comment without quoting when handing a "no longer needed" flag. Especially so if you don't feel that you have the time to add those comments to make a answer (more) useful; both you and they are volunteers.

Comment: @PeterCordes What about flags? _"Do you want to pay **mods** to spend even more time on them? No, didn't think so."_

Comment: @Cerbrus:  Yes, agreed on should've, but wasn't due to lack of time/effort.  We live in an imperfect worlds.  Moderator decisions should make it better, not worse.  The fact that an answer specifically says to see comments, and the OP of the question commented at the end of the discussion to say they were useful, are two big signs that those were useful comments and shouldn't have been moved to chat to rot in obscurity.

Comment: No, a wall of text like that (~1600 words) in the comments is never useful. It's noise. The noise might _contain_ useful information, but that's a diamond in the rough. It needs to be polished.

Comment: @Cerbrus: yes, I realize mods don't have time either to do a perfect job handling flags.  That's a fair point.  I can see in hindsight that my original flag wasn't worded super clearly to make a convincing argument for restoring comments, because I didn't think it was necessary; of course comments should get restored if someone asks, since useful comments get over-zealously deleted all the time.  I hadn't considered that people would waste mod time asking for non-useful comments to get restored so there'd be a canned msg like that.  (And that apparently not everyone shares my opinion on this.)

Comment: @Cerbrus: Never useful is a huge overstatement. A discussion between two experts can be interesting for others to read about; that's part of why usenet news groups and mailing lists were/are popular. It's not *as* useful as having the relevant info extracted and put into an answer, but it should be obvious that's not going to happen in practice for many of the comment discussions that exist on stack overflow. That doesn't mean it should get nuked, and then blame the authors of the comments for not putting in more effort to summarize and distill, and write up in a form that works in the answer.

Comment: There's so much noise in a discussion like that, that it's not useful from a Q&A perspective. That's simply how SO works. Comments are temporary. Always have been. If they contain _important_ information, it's the author's responsibility to move that information somewhere more permanent. Even the ["Comment everywhere" privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment#:~:text=How%20do%20I%20comment%3F,enter%20to%20submit%20your%20comment.) warns about comments getting deleted: _"There's no revision history, and when they are deleted they're gone for good."_

Comment: wait, so the warning on the comment everywhere privilege is a blatant lie?

Comment: @KevinB: these comments were merely _moved_ :D

Comment: @PeterCordes I must point out that you switched from "useful" to "interesting" there, those are not the same thing.

Comment: @Gimby: that's true.  Discussion between two other people is often not as directly useful for solving your own problem, but still interesting for learning about the broader subject.  So useful in a different way.  In this particular case, there was some actually useful info in these comments, too.  I'd still argue for "useful" being sometimes true as well, like in this case, not *just* interesting.  Again, not *as* useful as if someone took the time to distill into a form suitable for inclusion in an answer, but that takes more work.

Comment: Imagine how much useful information you could've distilled out of the discussion in the time you spend arguing the usefulness of said discussion...

Comment: Also, does nobody agree with *anything* I'm saying?  The entire comment section and voting on it seems like everyone piling on against me.  The question has 9 upvotes but 17 downvotes, so at least not everyone thinks I'm being unreasonable.  But none of my comments have any upvotes, and a bunch of "you must be dumb" comments have multiple upvotes, and ones basically telling me I should have already included the comments in my answer if they were useful.  Yes, of course, but nobody has time to perfectly craft every answer.

Comment: @Cerbrus yea but it says when comments are deleted they're gone for good, that's clearly false, since mods can see deleted comments.

Comment: @Cerbrus: I'm arguing for the general principle of the thing, that useful comments shouldn't be deleted, and should be restored when people ask.  Of course I could have spent this time delving into that old answer.  So could you, instead of spending more of your time on meta, but obviously we chose not to because we also care about how SO works and how it gets managed.

Comment: There are 2 separate issues here, Peter. 1: This specific case of deleted comments, 2: Your opinion that comments are too easily deleted. Please don't mix these issues into a single discussion. If you want to change policy, make a suggestion on Meta. If you want to discuss a specific case, this looks like the question to discuss it on.

Comment: @Cerbrus: When I wrote this question, it was about an intentional refusal to undelete.  Which does of course tie this specific case into the general policy.  It turns out that probably wasn't intended or agreed upon by all moderators, so this meta question got off on entirely the wrong foot.  But people commenting did discuss the subject of the comments in general, and here we are having a discussion that's already gone off the rails.

Comment: @PeterCordes where has anyone commented anything even remotely similar to "*you must be dumb*"? If you see such comments, please flag them as rude. I see people upvoting comments that explain how your viewpoint is incorrect, nothing more.

Comment: @TylerH: Not literally insults, but for example *Why would you do that when you know that comments can and do get deleted.* - obviously it's much less work to edit in "see comments", and blockquoting them would be ugly.  Or your comment "*How can you claim the comments should not have been deleted because they were still useful, and at the same time not know what they said?*" - when this meta question already explained sufficient detail to understand why that would be the case.  So not directly insulting, but feels like it portrays me as being silly for future readers of the comment thread.

Comment: @PeterCordes I read your entire post and still didn't have an answer to that question since it's logically impossible, so I'm not sure how you can consider that insulting. Instead of being insulted, instead don't take things personally. It sounds like you are giving yourself preferential treatment here ("I trust my 2018 self" (about a non-sequitur)) and expecting it also from mods/other users. It's one thing to expect a user of a certain account age or reputation/participation level to tend to know things, but it doesn't work in the other direction; users don't get deference for wrong things.

Comment: Mods don't let users keep comments around that are NLN just because they have 300k rep, same as they don't let users post questions as answers, etc. If I'm bring frank, yes, you have been portrayed as being a little silly here for future readers because you at this stage ought to know better than to 1) expect comments to stick around forever, no matter how useful you think they are 2) complain to mods when they get deleted, 3) post a long rant on Meta about the situation, and 4) continued talking about the issue instead of taking the win when Martijn corrected the crux of the issue.

Comment: @TylerH: I'm not arguing for keeping NLN comments, I'm suggesting that my judgement of whether a comment was NLN or not might have some weight.  And I'm not seeing what's a non-sequitur.  In 2018, there were useful comments.  I edited my answer to say so.  In 2022 they were gone, but my answer still said there were useful comments.  Therefore, there are must be some useful deleted comments.  You might disagree that comments can ever be useful, but is that argument not clear from my meta question?  If not, any suggestion on how I could make it clearer?

Comment: That this post has received any upvotes at all is likely only due to said deference (with, I admit, perhaps a couple users who agree comments should not be deleted the way they are Stack Overflow); this is a classic example of "user comes to Meta to rail against mods for doing some bog-standard action" that _normally_ just gets dupehammered and downvoted into oblivion.

Comment: @PeterCordes The argument is clear, it's just not persuasive, because it's wrong. In 2018 there were useful comments, but you didn't bother specifying _what_ was useful about them. There's no way for us to know if a deleted comment was useful in a time- or other context-specific manner. Just because your answer still says "check the comments" doesn't mean those comments were wrongly-deleted, it just means you haven't bothered updating your answer to reflect the fact the comments were deleted.

Comment: @TylerH: My answer did say what's interesting about them: performance considerations. The question primarily asked if something was *possible*, and whether it's worth doing in a specific situation is complicated, although the question implied it was interested in performance.  The full text was *See discussion in comments: this might perform significantly worse. Definitely benchmark both ways before doing this, preferably on a variety of hardware including multi-socket systems.*

Comment: that's mostly irrelevant, the comments were moved, not NLN deleted. A bug resulted in a comment that should have been put in it's place also being moved.

Comment: @TylerH: I can see with hindsight that this was just a couple human/computer mistakes, including in handling my flag, as well as in the initial moving to chat process. (And my own assumptions). But I feel like nobody's willing to see this from my perspective at all, not knowing that was a canned decline message, and making a wrong assumption that a mod had considered the situation in detail before choosing to reject with that message.

Comment: @TylerH: If even one person would say something like "I can see that this looked a lot worse from that perspective, but that's probably not what was going on", that would feel a lot different to multiple people saying (or upvoting) I'm taking this way too personally and shouldn't have known I could try flagging again with different wording.  I don't find that reasonable at all, IDK how I should have realized it was just a wording problem for my first flag, not disagreement making it possible to even see the comments so I could.

Comment: If you approached this problem by instead asking for help recovering these comments, rather than immediately accusing people of wrongdoing, I'd like to imagine the response here would have been very different and you still would have gotten the help you wanted.

Comment: @KevinB: I did ask for comments to be undeleted, with a flag.  And got a moderator response which seemed incredibly hostile and unhelpful in this case.  I fully realize that if I'd guessed that response was just a canned response, I could have proceeded very differently, like trying again.  But the whole "comments are ephemeral" attitude on Stack Overflow is something I think is really dumb, so once I started writing this while angry about something, it unfortunately grew a section with a rant about that.

Comment: @KevinB: I leapt to the conclusion that folks who prefer tidyness had started a new attack in their war on useful comments, and this was a counterattack to a (fortunately non-existent) shift.  But I still stand by everything I said about how much it sucks for comments to be deleted without considering their value.  I'm seriously considering editing other people's answers even more instead of commenting, now.

Comment: So by your own admission you completely overreacted to a mundane flag rejection, and you continue to defend that overreaction... You could also just own up to it and apologize.

Comment: @Cerbrus: I think my reaction was justified given what I thought and knew at the time.  I apologize for the misunderstanding, though.

Comment: @Cerbrus: I'd be more willing to apologize if I got any apology or sympathy in return.  Everyone piling on an telling me I'm wrong for even considering that comments could have value doesn't put me in a conciliatory frame of mind.  Multiple things went wrong, leading to me getting an unpleasant experience, and you want *me* to apologize for it? (to you?)  No thank you.

Comment: You nearly have 300k reputation. You're active enough on Meta as well. I don't believe for a second that you're unaware how comments work on SO, and I don't believe for a second that you didn't consider that the rejection message could be template text. And even _if_ you are as ignorant about that as you claim to be, then that's on you, and you alone. _"Everyone piling on"_ is just your interpretation of people trying to explain how the site works, while you insist you weren't doing anything wrong, in a rather (passive-)aggressive tone.

Comment: It's like you're complaining you didn't know you can't walk on the grass when the sign that says you can't has been in that grass for 30 years.

Comment: @Cerbrus: My initial impression of that decline message had me seeing red, so no, I didn't consider that it could be a canned message.  Probably whoever chose it didn't consider the possibility of it coming across this way, but it did. In your grass analogy, it's a sign on the grass that people have been mostly ignoring for most of those 30 years, with moderators having previous restored deleted moved-to-chat links when I've flagged to ask for it; from my perspective that's just the obvious thing to do. So when that doesn't happen, the obvious conclusion is that some mod is changing status quo

Comment: @Cerbrus: You seem to be arguing that my feelings are invalid.  I find that utterly unconvincing and unhelpful.  THB, it's just making me more angry about the whole thing and how stupid it is that there's nowhere non-ephemeral to put anything other than answers.  And that useful comments get deleted even when they're doing no harm, on obscure low-traffic questions.

Comment: @Cerbrus: Given the way comments work on SO, it makes sense to have that "sign on the grass", so comments can be deleted when there's an actual problem, like on popular/canonical answers where they build up.  That makes total sense to me, to keep the rule wide open so any comment *could* be deleted at any time, but leave it up to sensible humans not to do it willy-nilly.  That's been my understanding of the de-facto comment situation, except for some occasional over-zealous moderation like Samuel Liew a few years ago.  (Which was part of the problem here in moving those to chat.)

Comment: Regarding the decline message (I wasn't the one that wrote it): We are often forced to be a *lot* less polite and explanatory than we'd like to be (anyone on meta knows we don't shy away from long messages) due to the overly short restriction on their length.  We aren't able to write more than 200 characters, so it's often a lot of work or impossible to edit the messages into something that comes off as polite (and due to various issues with the system, they're often never seen). We're generally in the mindset of cramming as much info into as little space as possible when writing them.

Comment: @RyanM: It wasn't the terseness, it was the tone-deafness of "If it's important, extend your answer." - With what?  Or if it's talking about other future answers / edits, that seemed a very "you snooze you lose" attitude to the comments on the flagged answer.  So unfortunately the info that part of the message conveyed came across as rude and intentionally unhelpful.  I guess you're saying there wasn't room to expand on that point to avoid the misunderstanding?  Fair enough, that's unfortunate.

Answer (score 24):

The comment thread, consisting of 27 comments, was [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/176005/2018/7/15).

Unfortunately, the script that added the moderator comment pointing to the chat removed not only the existing comments, but also the comment pointing to the chat. Not a useful outcome.

I've restored that comment now, so you can at least see the chat transcript. Use it to update your answer!

Comments are and always have been ephemeral, and subject to deletion without warning. We want to keep questions and their answers, not comments, so please don't count on comments existing forever.

Comment: Thanks, already updated my answer to include the chat link.  I hate that highly useful comments get moved to chat in the first place, mere hours after the answer was posted, and an hour after I edited my answer to tell future readers to have a look. (And the OP of the question specifically commented that the discussion had been useful.)

Comment: We've had this pattern happen before: comments moved to chat, and then after a while some "no longer needed" votes build up on the chat link and it gets deleted.  Previously moderators have been willing to restore the "moved to chat" link, which is better than nothing, and another comment can summarize why it was worth looking at.  Your answer doesn't address the unhelpfulness of the moderator response in this case.

Comment: @PeterCordes: again, comments are ephemeral. Useful or not, comments get deleted all the time. Don't count on them sticking around. If there is useful info in them, put that info in the answer.

Comment: @PeterCordes: I can't comment on the moderator action as I wasn't involved with that. I'll give the moderator a heads-up.

Comment: What good are comments, then, if even useful ones on obscure questions actually are going to get deleted arbitrarily?  Of course it's better to have more details in answers, and I aspire to that, but how does destroying actually useful info help anyone?  As motivation to spend even more time editing answers?  I do put effort into maintaining my answers, but there's only so much you can stuff into them without getting over-crowded.  And like I said, only so much time / effort in a day.  I don't mind the "police state" policy for comments (automatically guilty) as long as it's not over-enforced.

Comment: You could always link to the chat in your answer, if you don't want the link to be removed should the the comment get flagged @PeterCordes . But adding the actual content of the chat to the/an answer would be the real solution still, especially if the information is as important as you imply. In my honest opinion, if the information isn't important enough for you to consider adding it to an answer, then it isn't that important and *if* the link is lost it doesn't matter.

Comment: @PeterCordes: the intent with moving the comments to chat was to *not just delete them*. That the link to the chat was removed too was unfortunate, that's been reinstated now. Note that the moderators are human too, and volunteers to boot. Mistakes happen, that's been rectified now.

Comment: Was the procedure taken here done in a new/unusual way? Did Sam use a custom script that had recently been tweaked, for example? I feel like usually the moderator comment about moving stuff to chat doesn't get deleted.

Comment: @Larnu: No, I couldn't have added the chat link to my answer.  I do in fact do that sometimes when I see a comments-moved-to-chat comment.  But Martijn is saying that the moved-to-chat comment got deleted at the same time as the comments that got moved to chat (e.g. add comment then delete-all-comments, instead of the other order).  So I never got a notification of a new comment on that answer.  Not until Martijn restored the 2018 comment just now was I able to add the chat link to my answer.  That's why the situation looked so bad to me before posting this meta question.

Comment: The comment has been restored, @PeterCordes , so what's stopping you doing it now...? I wasn't talking in past tense.

Comment: @Larnu: I *did* do that within 1 minute of Martijn's first comment under my meta question, posted within a minute of me posting this meta question.  https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51344347/revisions .  So I assumed you were talking about at the time, in 2018.

Comment: Ok, great! But still, putting the actual information in the answer would be *far* better.

Comment: @Larnu: Of course it would, we all agree with that.  That's not at all the point.  It's a lot of work to distill a discussion into a form that's suitable for being part of an answer.  Especially when the answer and the subject matter isn't still fresh in ones' mind, being 4 years old, since it didn't happen at the time.  People continuing to tell me I should have edited everything from comments into the answer at the time just feels like victim-blaming.  Nobody has time to be perfect, so there will always be comments that people haven't gotten around to including in answers, which have value.

Comment: *"Nobody has time to be perfect"* And yet you blamed the moderator for *not* being "perfect" here, @PeterCordes , as they didn't read your answer when dealing with a flag on the comments and that when they took action they (presumably) did the operations in the wrong order due to being human. This was, at *best* a human error, and at worse a problem not caused by the moderator. I, and others, aren't victim blaming (in my opinion), but it *was* an avoidable problem which you could have handled; blaming a moderator for being human due your own inactions isn't "fair" in my opinion.

Comment: @Larnu: The primary complaint in my meta question is a moderator not restoring comments when I pointed out that there were useful comments that had been deleted.  And about the phrasing of the decline message (which I didn't realize was canned; but in hindsight that makes sense because it didn't seem very well suited to this case). I understand that comments will get deleted when they (IMO) shouldn't have been, that's not great but I understand that humans can make mistakes.

Comment: @Larnu:  I didn't consider the "moved to chat" message itself being deleted right away as a possibility since I assumed there was a single button that does that and then posts the message.  And apparently that is the case: Martijn says that was not *human* error, but a script wrongly deleting that comment, too. IDK what kind of error to categorize the declining of my flag; I edited my meta question to provide some perspective on the assumptions on my part that led to it, e.g. the assumption that of course deleted comments should be restored when someone asks, especially high-rep users

Comment: @Larnu: Do comments get moved to chat in response to flags?  My impression was that Samuel Liew used to just do that frequently of his own accord, even on obscure low-traffic Q&As.  That seems to have mostly stopped, fortunately.  But the initial moderator action that moved comments to chat was most likely not part of handling a flag.

Comment: @PeterCordes: the comments were removed in response to an automatic flag, raised when there are a lot of comments on a post.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Ah, I see.  That makes sense.  Seems like an unnecessary waste of moderator time to me, but I only hang out in lower-traffic tags like [assembly] and [cpu-architecture], where a good fraction of long comment threads tend to be useful and technical, not back-and-forth with newbies debugging.  (Although there are plenty of those, and it seems like they get moved to chat less often.  Or maybe I just don't notice, or selection bias of remembering the cases that irked me.)

Comment: @Larnu: You claim I expected moderators to be perfect.  I said whoever *flagged* those comments for deletion in the first place was wrong.  I know mistakes happen, and moderators don't have time to be perfect either. But when a mistake is spotted and pointed out with another flag, I expect a reasonable response.  Not something that sounds like "we're not fixing it; you should have done something differently 4 years ago".  It turns out that may have been yet another mistake while trying to get a mistake corrected, but you're putting words in my mouth about expecting perfection *all* the time.

Comment: @Larnu: I don't like how comments get deleted too often, but I can agree to disagree with that general policy as long as we can get problems fixed when they happen.  If that system were to actually break down (like it looked like was happening), that would be a huge problem.  That's what I was most upset about, because that would be a total breakdown in what makes an imperfect system usable. Comments like yours portraying me as making totally unreasonable demands that moderators never make mistakes and delete the wrong things are a deflection from the main point and misleading to other readers

Comment: @Larnu: Maybe the 2nd half of my meta question came across as the main point of the argument.  That wasn't intended, it's there for explanation of why it should be obvious that restoring the comments would be the right thing to do, and wandering off-topic into making a general argument for not gratuitously deleting useful comments on low-traffic posts, which is pretty much what de-facto does happen these days most of the time, but apparently people think that's *not* a good thing????  (But yes that part should have been posted as a separate meta question, sorry for my ADHD.)